# I am trying to save the notification title and body using shared preference but i am unable to

Tags: flutter, api, dart-null-safety

#I am trying to save the notification title and body locally and fetch the title and body inside my app to show all the sent notification in a listview but i am unable to

#this is the code i am running this code in my main.dart inside initstate and that detail.add is my list which i created manually but i am getting error saying 102:45: Error: This expression has type 'void' and can't be used.prefs.setString('notificationData', setData); when i try to setString this is the error i get

```
List<String?> detail = [];
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) async{
      if(message.notification!=null){
        // print(message.notification!.body);
        // print(message.notification!.title);
        final title = message.notification?.title;
        final body = message.notification?.body;
         SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
         final String notificationData = json.encode({"title":title,"body":body});
         final setData =  detail.add(notificationData);
        prefs.setString('notificationData', setData);
        print(notificationData);
        print(setData);
      }
```

Comment: you are calling setString and in arguments you are providing list of Strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `detail.add(notificationData)` function returns nothing (`void`) and only adds to the existing array, so your `setData` variable is empty but you can use the original updated `detail` array like so:

```dart
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) async{
  if(message.notification!=null){
    // print(message.notification!.body);
    // print(message.notification!.title);
    final title = message.notification?.title;
    final body = message.notification?.body;
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String notificationData = json.encode({"title":title,"body":body});
    detail.add(notificationData);
    prefs.setString('notificationData', detail.toString());
    print(notificationData);
    print(detail);
  }
//...
});
```

Comment: Thnaks it worked but now i am trying to getString and show it in listTile or listview like this     Future<String?> getNotification() async {
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        if(prefs.containsKey("notificationData")){
          prefs.getString('notificationData');
        }else{
          print("No Notification to show");
      }

Comment: but i am not getting the data and sorry for trouble

Comment: but when i save my notification in details then the new notification replaces the old notification

Comment: "but when i save my notification in details then the new notification replaces the old notification" => you need to first assign your `detail` array's value to the notifications already stored in your storage then add to it. It's being replaced because you're initializing it to an empty array at first

Comment: And no trouble at all :) . If you want add your new issues to the question with proper code formatting so I can add to my answer.

Comment: i was unable to ask a question the problem occured is that the notification which is saved using setString then new notification is replacing the old once and i also wanna get that list of notification inside my app in a card view or list view

Comment: Please check out my previous comment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70577824/trying-to-save-push-notification-using-shared-preference-and-get-that-title-and

Comment: i asked the question in proper format can u please check it? thanks