# trying to save push notification using shared preference and get that title and body

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-notifications

I am trying to save push notification title and body using shared_preference and and trying to get that saved data in my card view or listtile meaning i wanna show the list of notifications inside my app which i saved locally using shared preference:

```dart
    static List<String?> detail = [];
    
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) async{
      if(message.notification!=null){
        // print(message.notification!.body);
        // print(message.notification!.title);
        final title = message.notification?.title;
        final body = message.notification?.body;
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        final String notificationData = json.encode({"title":title,"body":body});
        detail.add(notificationData);
        final data = prefs.setString('notificationData', detail.toString());
        print(data);
        print(detail);
      }
      LocalNotificationService.display(message);
    });


    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) async{
      final routeFromMessage = message.data["routeKey"];
      // RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      final title = message.notification?.title;
      final body = message.notification?.body;
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final String notificationData = json.encode({"title":title,"body":body});
      detail.add(notificationData);
      final data = prefs.setString('notificationData', detail.toString());
      print(data);
      print(detail);
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(routeFromMessage);
    });
```

The data is being saved but my old notification is being replace by the new once and only the new once are showing

I am trying to get my saved data like this:

```dart
  Future<String?> getNotification() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.getString("notificationData");
  }
```

I wanna get all the list of my notification inside a card view or list view:

```dart
    Card(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getNotification(),
        builder: (context, notificationSnapshot) {
          if (notificationSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none &&
              notificationSnapshot.hasData) {
            return const Text("No Notification to Show");
          }
          return ListTile(
            title: Text("$detail"),
          );
        },
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Your functionality is proper but I think problem is somewhere else. Can you show your complete page code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**step 1**

first get `detail` list value

**step 2**

then append `notificationData` in `detail` list

so your list value can't replace with newer one.
hope its helpful

Comment: thanks it worked i appended and it works